# Why would an NSURLConnection generate this error, NSPOSIXErrorDomain "Operation Cancelled"?

Tags: nsurlconnection, ios9, nsurl

In iOS 9, I'm using NSURL with NSURLConnection and for one specific URL, it's generating the following error in the `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` delegate method.

> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=89 "Operation canceled"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=URL, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1,
>   NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 16,
>   capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb41d733370000000000000000},
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=89, NSErrorFailingURLKey=URL}

The request isn't being canceled, at least not by our code.  What's strange is that the error here isn't even NSURLErrorDomain, it's NSPosixErrorDomain.

A user in the field reported an issue and this is the root cause, but it's tough to determine exactly why this is happening.  Accessing this specific URL with curl on OS X(using the same request, User-Agent and all), doesn't produce this error, the response is completely as expected.  However, even accessing this specific URL from the iOS Safari browser still doesn't work.  It's possible there is some strange server configuration, but I wouldn't expect the error to be so general like canceled.

It's also been reported that this wasn't occurring with iOS 8.  There's nothing out of the ordinary about this URL, it just seems it can't pass through our stack.  No auth challenges or any kind of delegate callbacks occur, except for didFailWithError and it occurs immediately.  Anyone else seen this kind of behavior in iOS 9?

Update: The particular URL that seems to produce this error is NOT limited to our apps alone.  In fact, simply trying to access this particular URL in iOS Safari on iOS 9 produces the same error.  I managed to test this on iOS 8.3 in iOS Safari and the error was not reproduced.

Comment: POSIX errors come from the OS level (e.g. https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/27ffc00f33925b582391b1ef318b78b8bd3939d1/bsd/sys/errno.h#L233) so I'm curious if this is not lower level than `NSURL*` classes. Did you happen to find more information?

Comment: Hi, yes this is a posix error and my assumption is that it was generated from some kind internal error occurring.  What we eventually found was that this error was being caused by some kind of bug with the ssl/https handshake on our server side product.  In iOS 9, the underlying machinery in NSURLConn attempts to negotiate using HTTP 2 with the server, using SPDY.  Something wrong on the server side broke this handshake causing this unusual error to bubble up to app level.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, Joey!

Comment: By the way, you may want to answer your own question and self-accept to close this out once and for all. It's the only SO question w/ this error code

Comment: While trying to figure out what error would be spat out from using a `URLSessionDownloadTask` to download a file and when the disk space would run too low (something else would put data on the disk during the download). And the first thing that popped out in the logs was `NSPOSIXErrorDomain`, code 89.

Comment: Oups incorrect information above, that error was likely something else unrelated. Correct code for low disk space is 28. Same error domain though. "NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=28 "No space left on device"

Answer (score 1):

Could this be an ATS issue?  For apps linked against the iOS 9 SDK, iOS 9 uses stricter rules for what types of TLS certs it will accept, and for what TLS protocols it will allow (e.g. no more SSLv3).  Additionally, it requires that all requests be HTTPS (not HTTP).

You can either override this behavior (if you must) or fix the server.

For details, see Apple's [Info.plist documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/plist/info/NSAppTransportSecurity).

If that doesn't help, try enabling CFNetwork debugging as described in [QA 1887](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1887/_index.html) and see what it spits out.

Comment: Hi, we've fully opted out of ATS in iOS 9 by setting the appropriate structure in info.plist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Btw I wanted to mention that I have suspected that this issue could be related to ATS, but since it occurs in iOS Safari as well, I would think the behavior is isolated in the NSURL stack itself.  For instance, in iOS 9 using an app that uses curl instead of NSURL (iCurl from the app store), the error isn't encountered.  According to documentation we are fully opted out of ATS as we interact with many third party servers that we have no control over.

Comment: What do you get you type "openssl s_client -connect thehostname.com:443" in Terminal (substituting the correct hostname)?

Comment: Running it on OS X, I get the certificate chain and server cert back.  I'd prefer not to post any of that data.  I don't have any command line -like ssl utility for iOS to compare to.

Comment: The important question is what do you get for "Verify return code:"?

Comment: And are you running 10.11?

Comment: I believe I am running 10.11, yes.  $ uname -a
Darwin host.net 15.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.0.0: Sat Sep 19 15:53:46 PDT 2015; root:xnu-3247.10.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64     And the verify return code is always 0.

Comment: In that case, try it in 10.11 Safari, and see if it allows the connection, and try enabling CFNetwork debugging and see if you get any interesting errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97020/discussion-between-joey-carson-and-dgatwood).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some color to this issue, I'll explain our similar situation and how we are handling it.

The setup:

- We are using SPDY for HTTP/2 requests on iOS 9
- We were randomly receiving a NSPOSIXErrorDomain error with code 89; this is defined at a very [low-level in the OS kernel here](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/27ffc00f33925b582391b1ef318b78b8bd3939d1/bsd/sys/errno.h#L233)
- We ruled out most server conditions and lack of network as the cause

Root cause:

- We found that if we introduced a sleep into one of our backend routes, iOS would surface it as this cryptic POSIX 89 kernel error
- The timeout on the iOS side is exactly 120 seconds which is the TCP default max segment lifetime

What else we tried:

- If we set our server to use HTTPS instead of SPDY (HTTP/2), it timed out with a normal network connection error

How we're "fixing" it:

- Filing a radar with Apple to better understand why the timeout is properly handled for HTTPS calls but not for SPDY
- Making the assumption that the only time we'll see this error domain/code combination is during a network timeout, at which point we should retry under certain situations