# AFNetworking iOS11 - HTTP load failed -999

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, ios11

I have an app in production that has been running fine for a while. However, since iOS 11 - I am receiving this error:

> Task <51E07EF5-6F31-4E58-8818-7712CB3E49A6>.<20> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
>    Task <51E07EF5-6F31-4E58-8818-7712CB3E49A6>.<20> finished with error - code: -999

This happens on iOS 11 only. Also, it is not consistent. Out of five requests to the same URL, two will fail with this. On a Cellular connection, it happens less often, but its still there.

I am using AFNetworking and as said; this has never been an issue until iOS11.

Any ideas?

Update to add more details:

I am using SSL Pinning with valid certificates. My info.plist looks like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>url.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Using the SSL pinning like this:

```
    NSString *pathToProdCert = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"MY_CERT" ofType:@"cer"];

if(pathToProdCert){
       manager.securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates = [NSSet setWithObjects[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToProdCert], nil];
            manager.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey];
        }
```

**Update:** 
In response to the comments: this is how the manager is declared:

```
@property (nonatomic) AFHTTPSessionManager *manager;
```

The manager is initialised through an init method of my web service class:

```
-(instancetype)initWithBaseUrl:(NSURL *)url {

    self  = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
        self.manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    }

    return self;
}
```

It is only initialised once per app session.

**Update:**
As requested this is the `userInfo` inside the `error` that comes back:

> NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://MY_URL/PARAMS";
>       NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "https://MY_URL/PARAMS";
>       NSLocalizedDescription = cancelled;
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-999 \"(null)\" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=89,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}";
>       "_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey" = 89;
>       "_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey" = 1;

Upon more testing, I have noticed that if I recreate the network class, where the `manager`is declared - on each network call - I never get this error.

Comment: Did you set up the NSAppTransportSecurity settings in the info.plist?

Comment: @gotomanners -  Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I did, with the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads set to true.

Comment: Please add code how you declare manager? And how many times code for creating manager is called

Comment: Does the request gets cancelled anyhow? See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrorcancelled?language=objc

Comment: @marcusficner If it is, it is not my own code doing it; as I have not written code to cancel requests. Will check the link anyway - thanks.

Comment: Does the `NSError` object contain any more information (`userInfo`)?
Can you set a breakpoint on the Task's `cancel` method so you can see from the stack trace what is going on when the Task is cancelled?

Comment: @JörnEyrich Added the info from the [userInfo] to the question. As for a break point on Task - where exactly should I set it? Tried to figure out where icancel is set in the library - but couldn't see what causes the cancelled.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790260/why-would-an-nsurlconnection-generate-this-error-nsposixerrordomain-operation ? (Especially the comment by the question's author.)

Comment: See here similar issue: [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2895)

Comment: It's a bug on iOS 11, on iOS 11.1 this issue is fixed. Or you can update you TLS from 1.0 to 1.2. Source: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3999

Answer (score 4):

`-999` or `ErrorCancelled`

The initialized manager is not owned, and is deallocated shortly after it goes out of scope. As a result, any pending tasks are cancelled.

Create a singleton class with AFHTTPSessionManager and use that for all your requests.

**YourAPIClient.h**

```
#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"
@interface YourAPIClient : AFHTTPSessionManager
+(YourAPIClient *) sharedClient;
@end
```

**YourAPIClient.m**

```
#import "YourAPIClient.h"

@implementation YourAPIClient

//Singleton Shared Client
+(YourAPIClient *)sharedClient
{
    static YourAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

        // Initialize Session Manager
       _sharedClient = [[YourAPIClient alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
        // Configure Manager
        [_sharedClient setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];

    });

    return _sharedClient;
}
```

Comment: This I get and it was something I explored. What I fail to understand is why is this an issue on iOS11 + devices only and not earlier versions of iOS?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar case.
For our particular case the customers were using the app while inside a corporate network, which was injecting the company's certificates to every request. If the device doesn't have the company's custom CA, then the user would get this particular error.

Comment: This isn't an issue I'm experiencing. As mentioned, we experience this issue even on a cellular network. Which rules out a company cert issue. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem like a bug in iOS. The error code associated with the `HTTP load failed`(`CFErrorDomainCFNetwork`), `999` is for a cancelled request (`cfurlErrorCancelled`).

You have answered the question yourself. To get this to work on iOS 11, you should consider using a different manager for each call, as it appears that the network requests on one manager are conflicting with each other.

**Reference material:**

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3999
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork/cfnetworkerrors/1416998-cfurlerrorcancelled
[NSURLErrorDomain error code -999 in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073519/nsurlerrordomain-error-code-999-in-ios)